# Name of bottom part of window

Tags: qt, window

What is the name for the bottom part of a window, the part that says "For help, press F1"?[image: TextPad Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [textpad.com](http://www.textpad.com/img/screenshot/tp5_xp.png))</sub>

Why does Qt not let me hide it, or put something useful in it (like a word count)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the (aptly named) Status Bar.

The Qt-equivalent class is the [QStatus bar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html).

Answer (score 1):

this thing is named "status bar"